# HTML font size changing unpredictably in embedded browser (MFC)

Tags: html, c++, css, windows, mfc

I have an embedded browser control in my C++ / MFC dialog. It displays an HTML page with some transforms.

Everything renders fine, the transforms work and all that.

However! 
For reasons I cant fathom, once every two weeks or so, something happens to the font side. Sometimes its too large, sometimes too small. 
I go and change the CSS section of HTML to make the font size larger, it works for a couple weeks, then all of a sudden it gets too large, and I have to change the number back down again. Nothing I do to IE zoom levels, etc seems to have effect on the font size inside my MFC app.

I have a vague suspicion that it has something to do with networks connecting/disconnecting, but can not reproduce the issue.

Why would that happen, and how can I prevent that from happening?

Windows 10, IE 10.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>       

        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 0;
            width: 0px;
            height: 380px; 
            transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0%, 0%);
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 37px; /* <-- need to keep changing this */
        }

        .line1 {
            color: white;
            width: 1000px;
            text-align: center;
            transform: translate(-35%, 0); 
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id=CHtmlMirror bgcolor=black>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="line1">My Text</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with zoom levels in IE, making sure that you are using the same bitness as your application? If your application is a 32-bit application, launch 32-bit IE, and if your application is 64-bit, launch the 64-bit version of IE. Sounds like you accidentally launch the respective other bitness of IE every now and again, make changes, and thereby screw up the settings stored for your web browser control.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset css or [enable compatibility mode in IE10](http://imss.caltech.edu/node/1185).

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: What is "resetting CSS"? Changing the font size? I already do that and its a major problem, coz I dont know at runtime what size to put. I have to start the app, see that there is a problem, then go and fiddle with the CSS until I get font size right, only to have it jump to a new "zoom level?" in a couple of weeks. Also, checked the compat view check box is set

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution.

I can intercept the OnDocumentComplete method of CDhtmlDialog and ensure the zoom level is always set to some fixed value. Then tweak the CSS to look right for that zoom level, and it will not jump around again

```
void CMyDialog::OnDocumentComplete(LPDISPATCH pDisp, LPCTSTR szUrl)
{
    CComVariant zoomLevel;
    zoomLevel = 100;
    m_pBrowserApp->ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, &zoomLevel, NULL);
}
```